# JAXB - adapter for a library object

Tags: xml-parsing, jaxb, xmladapter

I want to read an integer (inside XML element) to a Semaphore instead of int, effectively calling Semaphore(int theInteger) .
Problem is - Semaphore doesn't have a default constructor. 
If it was a class I wrote I could either make a no-arg private constructor or write an adapter, but since I have no access to Semaphore - what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object that you are adapting with an `XmlAdapter` doesn't need to a no-art constructor.  You could set it up as follows:

```
SemaphoreAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Integer, Semaphore>
```

Then you would use the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation on the property of type `Semaphore` to reference the `XmlAdapter`.

Comment: Before reading your answer, I actually found an answer in the MOXy documentation [here](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/moxy/advanced_concepts006.htm). Did you write it?